# I have a SQL join. But, how can I display a category name just once?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need a little help with a simple SQL/PHP issue I'm having.  I have a list of tasks stored in a table and then categories for the tasks in a tasks_categories table.  There's a foreign key of categoryID linking the two tables.

What I'd like to do is to have it list the first category, then all the tasks.  Then, list the second category and those tasks.  Currently, I just have it listing the tasks in a tree format.

How would I modify my code (pasted below) to show the category name once and then it's tasks, followed by the next category, etc?

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT * FROM tasks join tasks_categories using (categoryID)');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $menu_array[$row['taskID']] = array(
    'taskName' => $row['taskName'],
    'parentID' => $row['parentID'],
    'categoryName' => $row['categoryName'],
    'required' => $row['required']
    );
}

function generate_menu($parentID)
{
global $menu_array;
$has_child = false;

foreach($menu_array as $key => $value) {
if ($value['parentID'] == $parentID)  { 
        if ($has_child === false) {
            $has_child = true;
            echo '<ul>';
        }
        echo '<li>' . $value['taskName'];
        if ($value['required'] == 1) {
            echo '<span class="required">*</span>';
        }
        generate_menu($key);
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
if ($has_child === true) echo '</ul>';
}

generate_menu(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the query with `ORDER BY categoryID ASC`.  Then you can just loop through the results, keeping track of when the category changes.  Every time it changes, you print the category name and then print the tasks, until you hit the next category.

```
$currentCategoryID = -1;
foreach ( ... ) {
    // ... 
    if ($categoryID != $currentCategoryID) { // Category has changed!
        $currentCategoryID = $categoryID;

        // Show Category Name
    }

    // Continue listing
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound too hard but I can't implement it for the life of me.  It keeps repeating the category names for every single task.  Any idea what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: Update your code with what you tried and someone can see what you did wrong. Why ask us to guess?